# C language: Why my code get infinite loop and how to use recursion to solve Merge Sort problem?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

There are two problems I encounter in this code.

The first problem is the infinite loop, which happened from 77~79. When I change this test data and use merge method instead, I will get infinite loop and the R1 will be change to 4198739.But if I use mergeSort method, the problem won't show up as expected. Shown as below:

```
  int M = 2;
  int R1 = 4;
  int arr[] = {3,9,8,20};
  merge(arr, L, M, R1);
```

Second problem happened from 57 to 69 lines.In this mergeSort method, I tried to divide the unorder array into sub-array. However, there is no any effect on the original array.

Here is my code.
[Merge Sort in C](https://gist.github.com/edwardyi/e1090271ca4eba5492633807e941f4e0/revisions)

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int L, int R)
{
  if(L<R) { 
    return ;
  } else {
    int M = (L+R) / 2;
    mergeSort(arr, L, M);
    mergeSort(arr, M+1, R);
    merge(arr, L, M+1 ,R);
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(L<R) return;` Doesn't sound right, isn't the other way around? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: One reason you may not be getting much response is that the code is not all in the question.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  However, the left/right mnemonic of L and R indicates that your opening condition is wrong; it should be `if (L >= R)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in the logic of the code. I will address it the correct code.
A few pointers first.

1. The logic deals with array indices, don't confuse with array limits.
2. I have used sizeof operator to get the upper limit of the array.
3. Use if-else whenever possible.

The full code cannot be properly added here, so - https://pastebin.com/ixickcQA

Main mistake was here:

```
for(i=M;i<=R;i++)               //1. <= as R is also an index
{
     right[i-M] = arr[i];
}
```

Comment: The linked code does not compile!  *
untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:
untitled2.c:74:19: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         for(i=0; i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)); i++)
                   ^
untitled2.c:76:30: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
             printf("i=%d, R=%d,arr[i]=%d\n",i,(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)), arr[i]);
                             ~^
                             %ld*

Comment: It is just a warning, try running it.

Comment: Warnings should (almost) never be ignored.

Comment: I get that, but all the values expected here are within the signed int's range so it should not cause any problems. Also, I just ran it on CentOS 7 terminal C complier and it didn't show any warnings, it also executed fine. So please see if it is running fine.

Comment: Also I am new to this, so I had difficulties in adding the code. Please don't use that as an excuse to add a new answer.

Comment: I prefer to keep my fingers off other persons' answers,  Note: code needs to be indented 4 spaces to properly display in an answer

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to perform the same actions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188250/discussion-between-m-knight-and-user3629249).

Answer (score 0):

here is the code linked by the (other) answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    void merge(int arr[], int L, int M, int R) 
    {
        int LEFT_SIZE = M-L;
        int RIGHT_SIZE = R-M+1;
        int left[LEFT_SIZE];
        int right[RIGHT_SIZE];
        int i,j,k;

        for(i=L;i<M;i++)
        {
            left[i-L] = arr[i];
        }
        for(i=M;i<=R;i++)               //1. <= as R is also an index
        {
            right[i-M] = arr[i];
        }

        i=0;
        j=0;
        k=L;

        while(i<LEFT_SIZE && j<RIGHT_SIZE)
        {
            if(left[i] <= right[j])         //2. <= so that duplicates are not ignored
            {
                arr[k] = left[i];
                i++;
            } 
            else                    //3. use else to keep up the computing speed
            {
                arr[k] = right[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i<LEFT_SIZE)
        {
            arr[k] = left[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }

        while(j<RIGHT_SIZE)
        {
            arr[k] = right[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

    }

    void mergeSort(int arr[], int L, int R)
    {
        if(L<R)                     //4. Better
        {
            int M = (L+R) / 2;
            mergeSort(arr, L, M);
            mergeSort(arr, M+1, R);
            merge(arr, L, M+1 ,R);
        }
    }

    int main() {

        int arr[] = {3,9,20,8,21,22};

        mergeSort(arr, 0, (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int))-1); //5. Use size-1 as we are dealing with indices

        int i;
        printf("Final\n");
        for(i=0; i<(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)); i++) 
        {
            printf("i=%d, R=%d,arr[i]=%d\n",i,(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)), arr[i]);
        }
    }
```

so inserting the code into an answer is no problem

Answer (score 0):

In the `mergeSort` replace this:

`if(L<R)`

By this:

`if(L>=R)`

If `L<R` is present then it will always be satisfied because the index  `L` will always be less than than `R` (at starting). And this is the reason that you will get infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a logical error on your if-statement. Try this:

```
void mergesort(int a[], int l, int r) {
  int m;
  if (l < r) {
    // same as (l+r) / 2 but for avoiding overflow
    m = l + (r - l) / 2;

    // recur both parts
    mergesort(a, l, m);
    mergesort(a, m + 1, r);
    merge(a, l, m, r); // merging parts
  }
}
```